# Function / Algorithm that take fixed time to compute

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

I was wondering if there are any mathematical functions or algorithms that take a known minimum amount of time to calculate. The closest thing I could find to this is Proof of Work algorithms used for blockchain, but the speed at which hashes for these are calculated is affected by device hardware. I'm interested to know if there is any research into this? A function that would always take 100 ms to get the answer to for example?

Excluding sleep functions of course which rely on device clock. I need something this is completely device agnostic.

Comment: Do you mean same time whatever the value of the argument, or same time whatever the hardware ??

Comment: IMO this question makes little sense. If you increase the clock speed of a computer without changing any other aspect of the computation, the running time varies proportionally. Are you asking if there is an upper limit to a clock speed ? [In this sense, *every* function has a minimum running time.]

Comment: yes I suppose you're right @YvesDaoust I'm trying to find the theoretical maximum of hash rate of something like SHA256. I read new CPUs are optimised now with special instructions to make this faster. Surely there is a maximum hash based on like Plank lengths or entropy or something

Comment: Why didn't you ask the right question then ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example: When you unlock an iPhone, you enter a passcode, and the passcode needs to be checked. That takes exactly 80ms, no matter how fast your phone is. Why?

To check the passcode, the passcode is hashed n times, and then the hashed passcode isn't just checked, but used to decrypt a key, and if the passcode is not right, then you figure out very quickly that the decrypted key doesn't work (so nothing is ever stored that you can use). The number n is determined when you create the passcode, and it is set just large enough that n rounds of hashing take 80ms *on your phone*.

What if you run it on faster hardware? It doesn't work. The hardware itself is part of the hashing algorithm. It doesn't work on an identical iPhone, because the CPUs are not identical. And it doesn't work on some supercomputer with a few thousand cores, because it doesn't work without the CPU in your phone.

The 80ms is chosen so that a normal user doesn't notice it at all, but a hacker who somehow convinces your phone to try all passcodes, one after the other, is stack at the 80ms per passcode limit.

Comment: This is similar to the "sleep" case. Recall "I need something this is completely device agnostic."

Comment: Hey this is a great answer! Is there any link for further reading on this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, I don't believe this is likely to be possible.  It is possible you might be interested in timelock puzzles, which address some of the issues you raise with [proof-of-work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work) and [computational puzzles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_Puzzle_Protocol).  If you are looking for a purely computational solution, that is as close as you can reasonably get.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/89094/971, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/606/351.

Alternatively, if you don't need a purely computational/algorithmic solution, then you can use trusted hardware, perhaps combined with a [trusted time service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping).